# Call member function for each element of std::tuple

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17, stdtuple, index-sequence

I've been searching the most simple and elegant solution and found this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>


struct A{
  void hi(){
    std::cout << "HI\n";
  }
};

template<typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
void unpack(Tuple& tpl, std::index_sequence<Is...>){
  ((std::get<Is>(tpl).hi()),...);
}

int main(){

  std::tuple<A,A,A,A,A,A> tpl { A(), A(), A(), A(), A(), A() };

  unpack(tpl, std::make_index_sequence<6>{});

  return 0;
}
```

However, i do not completely understand this line:

```
((std::get<Is>(tpl).hi()),...);
```

I understand what it does, but what is that kind of syntax?

Is it somewhere in standard?

Comment: It's a variadic template.

Comment: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) that does

```
(std::get<Is>(tpl).hi())
```

for every `Is` that is packed inside.